# How to create a custom map based search bar like yelp?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web2py, yelp

So I am trying to create a search bar like yelp's that gives places suggestions and the map markers reflect those suggestions as well. I was able to implement a google maps places search bar from the google maps api however, now I want the places search to only show place suggestions on the map that are in my database. How would I go about implementing this? Detailed explanations, tutorials or references would be very helpful.

Comment: What you are looking for is a simple AJAX search with suggestions. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp plenty of examples everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A good option for this is to use [Jquery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).  In web2py you will need to write a controller function that will be called via ajax from jquery UI.  Something like (untested):

```
def places_lookup():

    import json 
    term = request.vars.term
    places = []
    if term:

        rows = db(db.place.name.startswith(term)).select(db.place.name,
                  orderby=db.place.name, limitby=(0,10), distinct=True)

        for row in rows:
            place = dict(name=row.name
                         )
            places.append(place)

    return json.dumps(places)
```

You'll call this function from javascript using a url like:

```
var url = "{{=URL('places', 'place_lookup.json')}}?term=" + request.term;
```

You'll have to read the jquery ui documentation to understand how to setup the javascript.